# Child process not continuing execution when ptrace'ing

Tags: c, linux, debugging, ptrace

I made the following simple example to read memory from a child process using ptrace.

I want to see the value at a specific address, 0x601050, every second during the execution of a small matrix multiplication program. I use PTRACE_PEEKDATA followed by PTRACE_CONT and sleep for 1 second, in an infinite loop, to do so.

However, the matrix multiplication program never proceeds--it should print to stdout in the first instruction, but it never seems to execute. I understood that ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,pid) would signal the child to resume execution and that sleep(1) would allow it to execute for a second (until the next ptrace call), but that is not the case.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>

int read_mem(long *out, pid_t pid, long addr, size_t sz)
{
    long tmp;
    size_t copied = 0;

    while(copied < sz)
    {
        tmp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, addr+copied);

        if(errno)
        { 
            fprintf(stderr,"ptrace: error : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            return copied;
        }

        memcpy(out,&tmp,sizeof(long));

        copied += sizeof(long);
        out++;

        printf("ptrace: copied %d bytes\n",copied);
    }

    return copied;
}

int main()
{   
    pid_t child;
    long result;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    int status;

    long addr = 0x601050;
    size_t sz = sizeof(double);
    long *buf = (long*)malloc(sz);

    child = fork();

    if(child == 0) 
    {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME);
        execl("./matmul", "matmul", NULL);
    }
    else 
    {
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, &regs);
        printf("ptrace: regs.rip : 0x%lx\n", regs.rip);

        while(1)
        {
            read_mem(buf, child, addr, sz);
            printf("ptrace: read(0x%lx) : %f\n", addr, (double)(*buf));

            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child);

            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you be calling `ptrace` with variable number of parameters?

Comment: It compiles/runs fine, I figured ptrace defaulted the remaining values to 0 or NULL

Comment: I should've posted this earlier, but @ooga that was exactly the issue. For some reason it allows me to compile and run with a variable number of parameters to ptrace, but it doesn't execute as expected. Adding the 0/NULL arguments fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to set a PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC option. Failing to do so results in SIGTRAP being sent to tracee upon a call to exec; if it is not prepared, the default action is a termination with a core dump.

Comment: I understand that using ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME) traps the tracee on the next call to exec, but shouldn't ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,child) let it resume execution?